# How to Start Snort on OpenWRT?

Tags: linux, logging, service, openwrt, snort

Recently I replace my router OS with OpenWRT, and I've install snort(2.9) on it with :

```
opkg install snort
```

My One and Only rule in `/etc/snort/rules/local.rules` :

```
alert icmp any any -> [My Router Private IP like : 192.168.0.1] any (msg: "NMAP ping sweep Scan"; dsize:0;sid:10000004; rev: 1;)
```

The problem is when i run :

```
snort -A console -q -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -i br-lan --daq-dir /usr/lib/daq
```

On the command line, it is **Okay** and it detects some Nmap scan attacks and wrote the alerts in console :

```
04/12-08:19:50.152690  [**] [1:10000005:2] NMAP TCP Scan [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.0.10:46287 -> 192.168.0.1:22
```

and log file, But when I start the service by :

```
/etc/init.d/snort start
```

Nothing happens and no log file created when I use same Nmap command (`nmap -sX -p22 192.168.0.1`).

My Questions are :

1. Why the server is not running ?
   There is no way detecting if every thing okay with service without Systemctl.
2. Why the log created when i run snort command is nonsense?
   When I type for example `cat /var/log/snort/snort.log.1523473976`  I get :

   �����Z�^8Mvv�n6(爈���Ehu�@@A3��<���

in the console.

**PS** :
1 -`cat /etc/init.d/snort` :

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common
# Copyright (C) 2015 OpenWrt.org

START=90
STOP=10

USE_PROCD=1
PROG=/usr/bin/snort

validate_snort_section() {
    uci_validate_section snort snort "${1}" \
        'config_file:string' \
        'interface:string'
}

start_service() {
    local config_file interface

    validate_snort_section snort || {
        echo "validation failed"
        return 1
    }

    procd_open_instance
    procd_set_param command $PROG "-c" "$config_file" "-q" "--daq-dir" "/usr/lib/daq/" "-i" "$interface" "-s" "-N"
    procd_set_param file $CONFIGFILE
    procd_set_param respawn
    procd_close_instance
}

stop_service()
{
    service_stop ${PROG}
}

service_triggers()
{
    procd_add_reload_trigger "snort"
    procd_add_validation validate_snort_section
}
```

2- I actually followed [This link](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/snort) to configure. but I uncomment and set `config logdir`: to `/var/log/snort/` .

(Any help would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: Maybe you can try `sh -x /etc/init.d/snort start` to see the debug output to understand what happens in this case, when preparing the command line via that script.

Answer (score 0):

It's set to localhost by default - `lo`
Check the output of `uci show snort.snort.interface`

You can change it with `uci set snort.snort.interface=br-lan`
Restart snort to confirm it has actually taken the new parameters - `/etc/init.d/snort restart`

You can view the whole command line in `top`/`htop`
If all is good, save the changes to UCI:  `uci commit`
And your logs are binary with that config, not text, I have mine log to syslog and send them to a remote rsyslog server, in snort.conf - `output alert_syslog: LOG_AUTH LOG_ALERT`